Mercado libre API (ID)
For example, when I make the following request:
curl -X GET https://api.mercadolibre.com/users/1477536226/brands
I receive this response:
{
   "status": "LINKED",
   "cust_id": 1477536226,
   "site_id": "MLA",
   "user_type": "brand",
   "brands": [
       {
           "site_id": "MLA",
           "official_store_id": 1450,
           "name": "Nike",
           "type": "brand",
           "relevance_position": 10000,
           "status": "active",
           "fantasy_name": "Nike",
           "date_created": "2018-04-26T13:30:28Z",
           "return_policy": null,
           "landing_permalink": "https://www.mercadolibre.com.ar/tienda/nike",
           "pictures": [
               {},
                   "size": "160x80"
               {},
                   "size": "160x80"
               {},
                   "size": "1600x250"
               {},
                   "size": "96x70"
              {},
                   "size": "174x164"
               {},
                   "size": "200x200"
               {},
                   "size": "1024x747"
               },
               {},
           "tags": [
               "TOP_BRAND"
           ],
           "categories_ids": [
               "MLA1276"
           ],
           "main_categories": [
               {
                   "id": "MLA1276"
               }
           ],
           "permalink": "https://tienda.mercadolibre.com.ar/nike",
           "normalized_name": "nike",
           "last_updated": "2023-12-12T19:28:34Z"
       }
   ],
   "tags": [
       "large_seller",
       "messages_as_seller",
       "brand"
   ]
}

As you can see, the official_store_id is present here ("official_store_id": 1450). However, I haven't been able to find a way in the documentation to retrieve the official_store_id for other stores or brands.
Does anyone know how I can retrieve the official_store_id for all official stores? Am I missing something in the documentation, or is there another endpoint to use?
